# Potassium from Potassium superoxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, synthesis

Is it possible to get $\ce K$ from $\ce K{O_2}$ using a synthesis reaction? If yes, can you describe it?

Comment: I suppose easier and/or cheaper ways are preferred. KO2 assumes it has (probably) already been K once. It is like to isolate K twice. // Attempts to post the most laconic question ever are at risk they will be closed and most users will not notice them.  [How do I ask a good question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: $\ce{KO2}$ is a dangerous and explosive substance. Don't use it. Better destroy it in large amounts of water.

Answer (score 2):

Thermal decomposition should help but it requires very high temperature. It goes through various oxides and ultimately decompose to potassium.

$$\ce{KO2 ->[<400 ^\circ C] non-stoichiometric oxides ->[400-480 ^\circ C] K2O2 ->[500 ^\circ C] K2O ->[560 ^\circ C] K (+oxygen ^)}$$

Do note the reaction is performed in vacuum otherwise it can oxidized back to peroxide/superoxide.

**Ref**. STUDIES OF THE THERMAL DECOMPOSITION OF THE POTASSIUM OXIDES IN THE TEMPERATURE RANGE 300--480 DEGREES C, RILEY, JOHN F. **1968**. ([link](https://www.proquest.com/openview/6b863e0ace6034ea19a5a80f7c50feb4/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=18750&diss=y))